# How can I sort data by fields in record in Batch-Execution mode using Flink DataStream api?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-batch

I need to write a batch flink job and I prefer to use DataStream api.

I want to make the output of the job sorted wihtin each output file(HDFS file). So that downstream can realy on these to speed up indexing.

Is there any replacement for [DataSet#sortPartition](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.14.4/flink-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/api/java/DataSet.java#L1480) in [DataStream API](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.14.4/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/DataStream.java)?

I read the [FLIP doc](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-140%3A+Introduce+batch-style+execution+for+bounded+keyed+streams#FLIP140:Introducebatchstyleexecutionforboundedkeyedstreams-Wheretoapplythesorting) says that for data in KeyedStream are sorted by key binary representation, Can I use this feature? Say making a String key composed of fields I want to sort by?

Answer (score 1):

Sorting is inherently a batch operation, as you have to first collect all the data so that it can be sorted (assumes no ordering on input data).

I believe Flink SQL would support doing an `ORDER BY`, but I haven't tried that.

If you're writing straight-up Java code, I assume you'd have create a custom `KeyedProcessFunction` that saves all incoming records into say `MapState` using the sort field(s) as the keys, then in the `close()` method you'd sort the keys and finally emit everything. But I've never tried that. And David Anderson should weigh in here :)

Comment: I prefer using DataStream api. If I have to use Flink SQL api, which means I should convert a DataStream to Table and back.